# Tinder-Style Swipe Functionality Using A PageView Widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm having an issue attempting to create a widget / some sort of setup that allows a user to swipe to the next page regardless of the swipe direction, similar to tinder-style swiping. I'm trying to do this using a `PageView` / `PageView.builder` widget due to it's ability to modify swipe physics. However, I'm having trouble being able to go to the "next" child in the list of widgets passed to the `children` parameter regardless of swipe direction.

Things I've tried:

1. Try to dynamically change the `children` of the `PageView` widget via a `setState` call
2. Attempted to create a custom `PageController` that would overwrite `previousPage` with `nextPage`
3. Using `flutter_tindercard` library. While it works, I'm trying to limit the number of dependencies while developing...

Flutter: v1.20.3 - Dart: v2.9.2 - Android Studio

If anyone has any suggestions on different widgets or approaches I could take it would be incredibly helpful!

Comment: https://github.com/himanshusharma89/Flutter-Tinder-like-swipe-app

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this solution exactly suits your needs but I used [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper) for similar thing and it worked almost perfectly.