# Tinder swiper in Flutter with PageView builder

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

How to create swiper like tinder with PageView.builder() in Flutter. It should be swipeable up and down, up - previous card, down - next card. Help me, please, I can't find any solution.

Comment: how about using `GestureDetector` and controlling `PageView` with only gestureDetector

Comment: @YeasinSheikh can u give me any example, please?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a package you can use: [flutter_swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper)

This is question was already asked here [Tinder-Style Swipe Functionality Using A PageView Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65013264/tinder-style-swipe-functionality-using-a-pageview-widget)

Comment: This plugin works bad, it copies last card in stack and mirrors it as first card in stack, when u try to put VideoPlayer on it, it plays on top of stack and from bottom, it is become a reason why player crushed